# cordova apk doesnt send ajax request

Tags: ajax, cordova, apache-cordova

I have developed an app using cordova(version 6.3.1). I have checked it on nexus 5 and nexus 6P and everything looks fine, but i tested it on genymotion emulator and galaxy S6, but they didn't send any request(I checked server logs).

Does it anything to do with security problems? Or there is another problem?

The ajax POST method is the code below.

```
    $("#login").click(function() {
    $.ajax(serverUrl + "/login", {
        data: {
            email: userEmail,
            password: userPassword
        },
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data) {
                //OK, Welcome!
                $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#welcomePage");
            },
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where is code...??

Comment: code added just now

Comment: real ... but i checked it on genymotion and nothing was sent again ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your part of source code where you have this problem ?

Did you check you have this plugin in your project ?

**cordova-plugin-whitelist**

Also, can you throw us your HTTP response when you're sending your AJAX request to your server

It may be, something like this :

```
            $.ajax
            ({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: ...,
                url: ...,
                type: 'POST',
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function (data)
                {

                },
                error: function(msg)
                {
                    alert("Error:"+msg.status + msg.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: i added the code ... i have this folder in my Plugins folder : cordova-plugin-whitelist